# Matrix integral involving a Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I need to evaluate the following matrix integral:

$\int_{P>0}\mathrm{det}(P)^{-1/2}\mathrm{det}(I+M\otimes P)^{-1/2}~_0F_1\left(\frac{d}{2}, -\frac{1}{4}SS^TP\right)~dP$

where $M$ and $P$ are $d\times d$ and positive-definite.

My first thought was to define $A=M\otimes P$ and make the change of variables $P\to A$. It's not too hard to show that

$dA = \sqrt{\mathrm{det}\left(J^TJ\right)}dP$

where

$J = (I_d\otimes K_{dd}\otimes I_d)(\mathrm{vec}(M)\otimes I_d)$

but now I'm unsure of how to proceed. I don't think that $A=M\otimes P$ has a convenient solution for $P$ in terms of $A$ and $M$, so just solving and substituting for $P$ in the rest of the integral doesn't seem to work.

Another approach could be to try and simplify $\mathrm{det}(I+M\otimes P)$, but I don't see any useful ways to do this. If we just had $\mathrm{det}(M\otimes P)$, then we could write it as $\mathrm{det}(M)^d\mathrm{det}(P)^d$ and not worry about any variable changes, but that's obviously not possible here.

Comment: $$\large{
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
I_d\;=\;\sum_{k=1}^d \:e_ke_k^T\\
\LR{I_d\otimes P}\;=\;\LR{M^{-1}\otimes I_d}A \\
P\;=\;\LR{e_1\otimes I_d}^T\,\BR{\!\LR{M^{-1}\otimes I_d}A} \LR{e_1\otimes I_d} \\
}$$